# Lightweight markup language for HTML5

Tags: html, markdown, markup

I've been using template toolkit + multi-markdown + Perl scripts as glue for my website.

This combination has a few problems:

1. I still have to do ugly things like:

   ```
   <div class=picture_right>

   {link to image}

   text for caption
   ```

with appropriate styling for picture_right.

2. To ensure that text is processed inside `<div>` tags, I have to add the flag `markdown="1"` to the `div`.
3. Seems I usually end up with a raft of surplus `<p>`tags wrapping things.  This keeps my output from validating properly, but otherwise seems harmless.

I think that HTML5 is mature enough now to use as an output format.  Such things as `figure`, `article`, footnote are clearer than `<div class...>` structures.

I'm looking for a lightweight markup language that has decent support to use HTML5 in a not too cluttered way.

Ideally:  Customizable to do things like: `H1` headlines automatically produce articles, `H2` produce sections, customization and defaults can be pulled in from external file.  (I'm just learning about the possibilities of HTML5.)

Answer (score -1):

All in all, you're trying to say you want to learn html5. I suggest Head First Html5 by Eric Freeman, Elisabeth Freeman.

Comment: No, I'm asking for a markup language to NOT have to learn HTML5